# Search a way to launch user default navigation app from my app with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, android-navigation

I search a mean like an "shareintent" to launch the user  default navigation app from my app.

I search long time on google, i find a mean to start google navigation but i would like to let the choice to my user to start his navigation app (like waze or an other app) there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + lat + "," + lng));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No because ACTION_VIEW is a generic action.
In my case it shows me this dialog https://imageshack.com/i/kpJXaXfyp